# Why Short Urls are denied in some countries is this crime?

Tags: url, short-url

I saw lot of website like [Su4u.in](http://su4u.in) [bitly.com](https://bitly.com/) they are just reducing the length of provided url and giving us short form of url. this helps us to share very easily and very efficiently then why it is denied in some countries?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: You may right but for information purpose it may be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You know about beacons? Bit.ly gets user information for analytic purpose.They are just not url shortners.

Comment: I don't have any idea about beacons,I need to search and what about [Su4u.in](http://Su4u.in)?